# getRuntime() results depends on Netbeans version

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using some lines of code to check whether a particular software program is running on my computer by checking the running processes on my computer. The full code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -x");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("/xyz/")) System.out.println("Found it!");
        }
        input.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception err) {
          err.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

When running these lines with Netbeans 8.2 I get a long list of running processes (about 90 processes in total). And the process I'm looking for is found. When I then run the same code using Netbeans 11.1 I get only a few processes (only 6 processes) and the process I'm looking for is not found. My computer's OS is Ubuntu. Both Netbeans 8.2 and 11.1 were installed in the default way, without any modifications by me. Both runs are done as the same user on the computer.

Why is there a difference in behavior between Netbeans 8.2 and 11.1? What can I do to have Netbeans 11.1 get all running processes on my computer?

Edit 1: based on suggestions in the comments have I verified running the program both from within Netbeans as well as from command line.
Both Netbeans 8.2 and 11.1 instruct to run the same command line:

```
java -jar "/home/joe/NetBeansProjects/Sandbox/dist/Sandbox.jar"
```

The results of this is identical to the results I get when I run the program from within Netbeans 8.2. The results I get from Netbeans 11.1 deviate from all other results (I get much less output).

Edit 3: here is the result of running `ps -x` either from my program in Netbeans 11.1, or from GNOME terminal. This is done two days later, and the number of running processes is slightly different from the time when I posted the original question.

Result of `ps -x` in Netbeans 11.1:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 tty2     S+     0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 34 netbeans-desktop
  190 tty2     Sl+    1:41 /app/jdk/bin/java <long command string>
  367 tty2     R+     0:00 ps -x
```

(3 processes found)

Result of `ps -x` in GNOME terminal (beware that the commands are truncated)

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2075 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
 2076 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
 2092 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 2096 tty2     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SH
 2102 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --n
 2109 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session
 2209 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL
 2211 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
 2216 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/default
 2218 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-s
 2232 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 2237 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o bi
 2255 tty2     Sl+    0:27 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 2265 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 2269 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulse/gconf-helper
 2271 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
 2281 tty2     Sl     0:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
 2285 tty2     Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
 2289 tty2     Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
 2292 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-portal
 2297 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal/xdg-permission-store
 2304 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 2308 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
 2316 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
 2330 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-identity-service
 2335 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
 2342 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 2347 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
 2351 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 2355 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
 2365 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power
 2366 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-print-notification
 2369 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill
 2372 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-screensaver-proxy
 2374 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sharing
 2382 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
 2385 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
 2389 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-wacom
 2390 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-smartcard
 2395 tty2     Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/gjs /home/joe/.local/share/gnome-shell/ex
 2396 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-a11y-settings
 2400 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
 2404 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-clipboard
 2408 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
 2409 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping
 2412 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-datetime
 2416 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
 2421 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard
 2436 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-mouse
 2467 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
 2472 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gsd-disk-utility-notify
 2483 tty2     Sl+    0:02 nautilus-desktop
 2484 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicato
 2489 tty2     Sl+    0:00 python3 /usr/lib/gnome-tweak-tool/gnome-tweak-tool-li
 2528 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.22 /org/gtk/gv
 2535 ?        Ssl    0:08 /home/joe/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-80.4.12
 2537 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
 2561 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subproc
 2567 tty2     Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
 2575 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
 2592 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subp
 2851 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
 3054 tty2     Sl+    0:00 telepathy-indicator
 3060 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
 3078 tty2     Sl+    0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
 3089 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 3096 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
 3137 tty2     Sl     0:00 python3 /usr/share/ibus-anthy/engine/main.py --ibus
 3216 tty2     SLl+   0:03 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
 3398 tty2     Sl+    0:08 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
 3532 tty2     S+     0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 34 netbeans-desktop
 3537 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-session-helper
 3542 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal/xdg-document-portal
 3552 tty2     S+     0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 34 /usr/libexec/fla
 3553 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-dbus-proxy --args=36
 3555 tty2     S+     0:00 /usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 34 netbeans-desktop
 3556 tty2     S+     0:00 /bin/bash /app/netbeans/platform/lib/nbexec --userdir
 3745 tty2     Sl+    1:48 /app/jdk/bin/java -Djdk.home=/app/jdk -classpath /app
 4149 tty2     Sl+    0:16 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
 4209 tty2     Sl+    0:17 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isF
 4252 tty2     Sl+    0:13 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isF
 4350 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/chrome-gnome-shell /usr/lib
 5226 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isF
 5513 tty2     Sl+    0:00 gedit /home/joe/Desktop/Empty Document
 5700 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
 5709 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
 5731 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps -x
```

(88 processes found)

Differences I observe: 
(a) Netbeans 11.1 only shows processes related to tty2. 
(b) Netbeans 11.1 does not show all processes belonging to tty2, only a subset.
(c) could it be that Netbeans 11.1 only shows processes which are related to itself, instead of everything that runs on the computer?

Edit 2: This is the information I get when I run **Help > About** in each of the Netbeans versions:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_131; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11
System: Linux version 5.0.0-27-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/joe/.netbeans/8.2
Cache directory: /home/joe/.cache/netbeans/8.2
```

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1
Java: 11.0.4; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.4+11
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.4+11
System: Linux version 5.0.0-27-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/joe/.netbeans/11.1
Cache directory: /home/joe/.cache/netbeans/11.1
```

I notice that the Java version is different. I don't know whether this can be the cause for a different result in the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command.

Comment: Just pasting a portion of your code is not enough for this issue. It really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so please update your question accordingly. The entire program should only be a few lines long. Also: [1] A couple of screenshots contrasting the different output might be helpful. [2] Update your question with the following information: (a) The version of Java you are using to build and run your code on NetBeans 8.2. (b) The version of Java you are using to build and run your code on NetBeans 11.1.

Comment: Were both versions of NetBeans installed the same way?  Are they both running as the same user?

Comment: @skomisa : I have expanded the code to be the full code I used for this investigation.

Comment: @VGR : Both versions of Netbeans were installed in their default fashion. I did not make any modification to their settings. I run the program as the same user.

Comment: What does it actually matter? You won't be running via NetBeans in production.

Comment: @Joe [1] That's good, but your question still does not include the output showing the problem, and still does not specify the version(s) of Java that you are using. Help us to to help you. [2] Also, when you run on NB 11.1, does you see the exact same 6 processes every time you run, or do those listed seem random?

Comment: @user207421 It matters because the issue might be due to the version of Java being used rather than the version of NetBeans being used. Pretty unlikely I admit, but then it also seems unlikely that using a newer version of NetBeans is the cause. Perhaps there is some permissions issue associated with the installation of the newer version of NetBeans?

Comment: @skomisa : [1] sorry, I must have overlooked you asking for the Java versions. I'm not sure where I can find these in Netbeans? I am of the opinion that showing the output does not really help in this issue. If I run "ps -x" in a terminal window I get the exact same result as when I run the above program in Netbeans 8.2. Running the program in Netbeans 11.1 gives only a few of all the processes. It is this Netbeans 11.1 result which deviates from the other two results.

Comment: @skomisa [2] I have the impression that each time I run the program in Netbeans 11.1 I get the same subset of processes. There does not seem to be any randomness in play. I see your other suggestion about "permissions issue", which could be but I don't know how to check or investigate for that.

Comment: @Joe [1] After building your application in NetBeans you should see a line near the end of the **Output** window stating _"To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:"_, and the following line will give the actual command to be run. Can you try copying that command, pasting it to the terminal window and running it, for both your NB 8.2 build and your NB 11.1 build? [2] Then update your question (rather than adding a comment) with the two commands you actually ran, and the results. Did they both work?

Comment: @Joe Can you tweak your code to run `"ps -f"` (instead of `"ps -x"`) to show the UID of each listed process. Do the UIDs that are listed offer any new insight on your problem?

Comment: @skomisa That is exactly my point, and that is exactly why the question being asked doesn't actually matter. It *does* depend on the Java version, and not at all on the NetBeans version. OP is barking up the wrong tree. And if he isn't, the question is irrelevant, as NetBeans won't be there in production. The only relevant fact is how the code behaves *without* NetBeans.

Comment: @skomisa I have followed your suggestion to run `"ps -f"` instead of `"ps -x"`. I get different results, again Netbeans 8.2 showing the same list as when I run the command in a terminal window, and Netbeans 11.1 only giving a much shorter list of processes. I have also experimented with a variety of other alternatives, using the ps manual page, but none helped me.

Comment: @user207421 I do understand your comment that production software is not run from within Netbeans. However, how am I supposed to debug my software if I don't get the correct results from running it within Netbeans? It seems to me that in such a situation Netbeans would not be suitable as development tool? My hope is that I will be able to modify whatever is necessary in Netbeans 11.1 settings to have it give the same results as 8.2. Otherwise it makes no sense for me to upgrade to this newer version.

Comment: @Joe You need to look at the Java version. Not the Netbeans version. That's the only thing that can change the behaviour. You appear to be using two different Java versions, which is already a mistake. You need to use the same version for testing as you intend to use in production, at least if you are getting undesirable results from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a request for more information that will not fit into the comments.

[1] Update your question with the output from the **Help > About** window for both NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 11.1. For example, on my machine this is what I get for NetBeans 11.1:

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1
Java: 11.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.2+9
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.2+9
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.1
Cache directory: C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1
```

[2] Build your application, and copy to the clipboard the command displayed in in your **Output** window specifying how it can be run from the command line. It will look similar to this:

> To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
>
> C:\Java\openJDK\jdk-12.0.2/bin/java -cp
>   D:\NB111\FormatProperties\dist\FormatProperties.jar
>   formatproperties.FormatProperties

Paste that command into the **Terminal** window and run it, for both builds (NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 11.1). What happens?

[3] Update your question with the `ps -x` output produced when running the application in NetBeans 11.1, and also from the Terminal window.

There are three possible causes of your problem:

- The version of Java that you are using with NetBeans 11.1. Obviously this is irrelevant if you are using the same version in both installations of NetBeans.
- NetBeans 11.1 itself.
- Some environmental issue related to your installation of NetBeans 11.1.

The three steps described above will help to isolate the problem.

---

Update:

Based on feedback from the OP regarding multiple Java installations, the next thing to try is to build and run the application using Java 1.8 in NetBeans 11.1. Doing this is a two step process:

1. Add Java 1.8 as a Java platform to NetBeans 11.1 (if necessary).
2. Rebuild the application and run it using Java 1.8.

To do this in NetBeans 11.1:

- Select **Tools > Java Platforms** then click the **Add Platform...** button (if Java 1.8 is not yet a platform).
- Select the platform type *Java Standard Edition* and click **Next >**.
- On the **Choose Platform Folder** screen navigate to the root of your java 1.8 installation. In my case it is **C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_221** but obviously your path will differ.
- Complete the wizard to add Java 1.8 as a Java platform, and click the **Close** button to close the **Java Platform Manager** window.
- Select your project in the **Projects** pane, right click and select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Set **Source > Source Binary Format** to *JDK 8*.
- Set **Libraries > Java Platform** to *Java 1.8* (or whatever *Platform Name* you chose earlier for Java 1.8), and click **OK** to close the **Project Properties** window.
- Select your project, right click and select **Clean and Build** to rebuild it with Java 1.8.
- Select your project, right click and select **Run** to run your application in NetBeans 11.1 using Java 1.8. Any change from using Java 11?

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your continued help during the last couple of days. I am not familiar with these IDE tools such as Netbeans and thus have to clue on how to investigate why I get different results with different versions of it. I understand the three potential reasons which you mention in the bullet list. I will update the original question with the information you ask for. Thanks again!

Comment: [1] I have added the **Help > About** information in the original question. Obviously have two different Java versions been used. I don't know whether these two versions treat the `getRuntime().exec()` command differently. [2] This command line was already included in the original question. Both Netbeans versions gave the same command to use. This command line does not include a clue about which Java version is to be used.

Comment: [3] I have included the output of `ps -x` from running the program in Netbeans 11.1, and from a GNOME terminal, in the original question. Could it be that Netbeans 11.1 only shows processes which are related to itself, and not all processes? I don't know whether Netbeans 11.1 has a setting which could enforce this.

Comment: @Joe [[1] I updated the answer to describe how to build and run your app in NetBeans 11.1 using Java 8. Can you try that? [2] What version of Java is shown when you submit **java -version** in the terminal window?

Comment: Thank you for including the procedure to add the Java platform. Now I am experiencing the next hurdle: Netbeans 11.1 does not allow me to select the same directory as Netbeans 8.2 does. The desired platform is in directory `usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131`. However, Netbeans 11.1 does not show folder `jvm` (obviously Netbeans 8.2 does). I will experiment a bit with folder settings to see if I can make it become visible.

Comment: Follow up on previous comment: changing folder settings did not work. Adding a path in `netbeans.conf` to define default jdk also did not work. Googling online has not given me any other clues. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @Joe OK. This suggests that the issue raised in your question is only a manifestation of a more fundamental issue with your NB 11.1 installation/environment, rather than a problem directly associated with NetBeans 11.1 or Java 11. Your inability to select your JDK 8 directory in NB 11.1 is probably off topic for SO, so perhaps you could try pursuing that on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), and then we can revisit your question here once you have Java 8 installed on NetBeans 11.1? I suggest focusing on the differences between your NB 8.2 and NB11.1 installations to get this resolved.

Comment: I tend to agree with your view that this problem is probably caused by the installation of NB 11.1. I will search for a solution.

Comment: @Joe OK, best of luck. Note that you can have multiple installations of NB 11.1, so there is no need to uninstall or delete anything you already have. You can [download a zip of NB 11.1 from here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+11.1) rather than installing it with an `sh` file.